# HTML CSS search BARwith GET method

Tags: html, css

I have the following to make a search using HTML With the username entered, for example 'user'

Then when the search bar is clicked, the page will go to http://localhost/searchuser/user

for example, with the GET Method from the input field. I'm having issues with this right now.

Is my implementation of `<form action="/searchuser" + username>` correct?

**Codes**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav .search-container {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav a, .topnav input[type=text], .topnav .search-container button {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;  
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


  <div class="search-container">
    <form action="/searchuser" + username>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username.." name="username">
      <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Search Bar</h2>
  <p>Navigation bar with a search box and a submit button inside of it.</p>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't. Only event attributes like `onclick` can take inline JavaScript code.
You can add a listener to the `blur` event of the text input and in the listener, change form's `action` according to the text input.

```
<form action="" id="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username.." onchange="document.getElementById('form').action = '/searchuser/' + this.value;" name="username">
  <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

In addition, even event attributes should wrap all the code into "".

```
action="/searchuser" + username
```

from another angle, is not a valid html attribute.